# Django - ManyToManyField - Display Admin form

Tags: django

I started to learn Django at school, I have a question about a manytomany relation between two tables.

A movie can have more than one review, the admin form only highlighted the reviews both for this record, but I would like to see both content, not as a list with all reviews id.

Thanks for your help.

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
     content = models.TextField(null=True)
     url = models.TextField(null=True)

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = "Critiques"
         ordering = ['content']

class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bms/photos', null=True)
    synopsis = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_available_in_theaters = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    reviews_list = models.ManyToManyField(Reviews)
```

[Admin form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeM3Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Then you should implement the `__str__` method for the review:

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    url = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content or ''

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Critiques"
         ordering = ['content']
```

The `or ''` is used here such that if `content` is `NULL`/`None`, then it will return the empty string, since `__str__` is supposed to always return a string.

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Review` instead of <s>`Reviews`</s>.

Comment: it's much better, but why it's returning all reviews instead of only 2 reviews which have created for this record?

Comment: @Yann: Because you select the ones you want to relate to the `Movies` object (you press Ctrl to select multiple ones). In order to thus select more/less/different `Reviews` object, you thus can select other ones, since this is a form.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I renamed my class to singular, I lost my data, I ave a backup, but what is the best way to avoid data loss?

Comment: @Yann: after you renamed it to singular, you need to make migrations, and migrate the database. It will then rename the table at the database side.